# Clickable relief (picture) of a country

Tags: java, android, shapes

I want to have a picture of a country in my android application. Country has to be split in regions. So when a user click on specific region, a specific screen should open. Regions should also be separated with lines, so the user can see where is start/end of the region.

Here is an example of a country (this lines are not really regions but is a good example of them - its only about 5-6 regions in reallity):
[image]

I don't know how to make:

- Layout for this kind of shape
- Lines, that separate the regions
- OnClickListeners for a specific region.

Any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with ImageMap for Android. Following links contains more info and a related project on git hub:

http://catchthecows.com/2011/08/09/ImageMap_for_Android/
https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap